# How not to dispatch addEventListener("scroll") when it is loaded and the initial scroll position is not at the top

Tags: javascript

This is a scroll event.
It works not only when scrolling but also when the scroll position is not at the top of the screen when loading.
Is there any way to keep this from igniting?

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
  console.log("load");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting until the page has entirely loaded:

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        console.log("load");
    });
});
```